# how to use setVariable in install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I have following code in install4J's startup sequence

```
Util.showMessage("before set sys.contentDir " + (String)context.getVariable("sys.contentDir"));

context.setVariable("sys.contentDir", "E:\\testApp");

Util.showMessage("After set sys.contentDir " + (String)context.getVariable("sys.contentDir"));
```

But the new value is not reflecting after setting the `sys.contentDir` by using the `setVariable` method.

Please help to achieve the functionality.

regards,
Jagadeesh Musham.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.contentDir` is a system variable that cannot be modified. To change the installation directory, use

```
context.setInstallationDirectory(new File("E:\\testApp"));
```